Allure Report not showing the body/annotations (Step/DisaplayName/Description). Using Junit 4
I had issues creating the report and finally was able to solve it and generate an Allure report (with the help of ChatGPT).
The issue is that no matter what I do, I can't see any annotations data like Step/DisaplayName/Description.
What I did is:

Clear the data with rm -rf build/allure-results/*"
Run the test (using the play button)


After I run the test, an xml file is created with this name:
TEST-HD1900 - 11-_app-.xml under build/allure-results.

this content of this file is:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<testsuite name="com.companyName.con.tests.PlayAds" tests="1" failures="0" errors="0" skipped="0" time="14.025" timestamp="2024-12-23T11:22:12" hostname="localhost">
  <properties>
    <property name="device" value="HD1900 - 11" />
    <property name="flavor" value="" />
    <property name="project" value=":app" />
  </properties>
  <testcase name="adOnLockScreenTest" classname="com.companyName.con.tests.PlayAds" time="11.617" />
</testsuite>


cp build/allure-results/debug/* build/allure-results/
This command creates another file with the same data

allure serve build/allure-results
This command opens the allure report with the correct result but without the annotations data


This is my gradle file:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.12.0'
}

allure {
    version = "2.29.1"
    useJUnit4 {
        version = "2.29.1"
    }
}



tasks.register('copyTestResults', Copy) {
    from(layout.buildDirectory.dir("test-results")) {
        include '**/*.xml'
    }
    into layout.buildDirectory.dir("allure-results")
}

tasks.register('copyAndroidTestResults', Copy) {
    from(layout.buildDirectory.dir("outputs/androidTest-results/connected")) {
        include '**/*.xml'
    }
    into layout.buildDirectory.dir("allure-results")
}

tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
    finalizedBy 'copyTestResults' // Unit test results
}

tasks.matching { it.name == "connectedDebugAndroidTest" }.configureEach {
    finalizedBy 'copyAndroidTestResults' // Instrumentation test results
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnit()
}

configurations {
    allureCommandline
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':ads')
    // Allure dependencies
  //  allureCommandline group: "io.qameta.allure", name: "allure-commandline", version: "2.32.0", ext: "zip"
    implementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.8.1'
    implementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-junit4-aspect:2.29.1'
    /////////
    androidTestImplementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-kotlin-commons:2.4.0'
  //  implementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-junit4-aspect:2.29.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-kotlin-android:2.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-junit4:2.29.1'

    // Other dependencies
    implementation ('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.3.14') {
        exclude group: 'META-INF', module: 'INDEX.LIST'
    }
    implementation ('ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.3.14') {
        exclude group: 'META-INF', module: 'INDEX.LIST'
    }

    // Kotlin dependencies
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.21"
    runtimeOnly 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:2.1.0'

    // Android dependencies
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.6.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.6.2'

    // JSON parsing
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.2"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.2"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.15.2"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.2"

    // Testing
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.callapp.contacts'
    compileSdk 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.callapp.contacts"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
    }

    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += [
                    'META-INF/FastDoubleParser-LICENSE',
                    'META-INF/FastDoubleParser-NOTICE',
                    'META-INF/NOTICE.txt',
                    'META-INF/thirdparty-LICENSE',
                    'META-INF/INDEX.LIST',
                    'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            ]
            merges += ['META-INF/INDEX.LIST']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    lint {
        abortOnError false
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
        exclude group: 'javax.activation', module: 'javax.activation-api'
    }
}

This is my test class (It's messy because of all the things I tried using chatGpt:
package com.compamyName.con.tests

import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.util.Log
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import com.callapp.contacts.BaseTest

import io.qameta.allure.kotlin.Attachment
import io.qameta.allure.kotlin.Description
import io.qameta.allure.kotlin.junit4.DisplayName

import org.junit.Before

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import io.qameta.allure.Allure
import io.qameta.allure.kotlin.Step
import org.junit.Test

class PlayAds : BaseTest(){

@Before
fun logAnnotations() {
    Log.d("PlayAdsTest","Setting up Allure annotations for test")
    Allure.getLifecycle().updateTestCase {
        Log.d("PlayAdsTest","Updating test case: ${it.name}")
    }
}

@Before
fun setupDebugging() {
    val lifecycle = Allure.getLifecycle()
    val currentTestCase = try {
        lifecycle.getCurrentTestCase()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("PlayAdsTest", "Error getting current test case", e)
        null
    }

    Log.d("PlayAdsTest", "Current lifecycle: $lifecycle")
    Log.d("PlayAdsTest", "Current test case: $currentTestCase")
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Test no impression")
@Description("This test verifies that no impression")
fun adOnLockScreenTest() {


    Allure.step("Step 1: Verify Allure works")
    Log.d("PlayAdsTest", "Inside simpleTest")

    Allure.step("Setting up test case details") { _: Allure.StepContext ->
        Allure.getLifecycle().updateTestCase {
            it.name = "Test no impression when device is locked"
            it.description = "This test verifies that no impression"
        }
    }

    Log.d("PlayAdsTest", "Entering testAdOnLockScreen")

    try {
        Allure.getLifecycle().updateTestCase {
            Log.d("PlayAdsTest", "Updating test annotations inside test")
            it.name = "Test no impression"
            it.description = "This test verifies that no impression"
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("PlayAdsTest", "Error updating test annotations in test", e)
    }

    Log.d("PlayAdsTest", "Exiting testAdOnLockScreen")

    val adBider = getRandomBidder()
    val layouts = nativeLayouts.random()
    chooseAndRunAd(adBider, rndAdTypeNoInterstitial(), layouts)

    Allure.step("Step 2: Lock device", Allure.ThrowableRunnable {
        Log.d("PlayAdsTest", "Performing lock device")
        lockDevice()
    })

   // lockDevice()

    //Give time for first impression to be presented
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    //  Thread.sleep(20000)

    Allure.step("Step 2: is device lock?", Allure.ThrowableRunnable {
        Log.d("PlayAdsTest", "Performing check if device is locked")
        isDeviceLocked()
    })

    handleMessages(startTime)

    attachScreenshot()
}

@Attachment(value = "Screenshot", type = "image/png")
fun attachScreenshot(): ByteArray {
    val device = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().uiAutomation
    val bitmap = device.takeScreenshot()
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
    return stream.toByteArray()
}

